# Flutter - en un ListView horizontal no se ajusta el ultimo item a la pantalla

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

Tengo un listview llenado con un FutureBuilder, de orientación horizontal con un gesturedetector para recorrerlo hacia los lados.

El problema es que el último item sólo se aprecia a la mitad y no se visualiza el resto, quisiera situarlo en el medio de la pantalla.

Es posible poner algún foco o bien forzar que cada item seleccionado se sitúe en el medio de la pantalla?

parte del código del listview es:

```
child: Scrollbar(
                      child: new ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: 3,
                        controller: scrollController,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            child: Padding(

                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Card(
                                child: Container(

                                  width: 300.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
```

Comment: Puedes usar PageView  , adjunta un screenshot para ver como se ve

Comment: Por qué tienes un physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() ?, esto evita que se mueva. Si te es posible agregar mas código a la pregunta, sera util para replicar tu problema y buscar una solución.